# Write a recursive procedure that returns how many times digit C appers in number N?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I write recursive procedure for this? 
N is an integer, and C<10. A procedure must return how many times digit C appers in N

Comment: Please refrain from asking questions if you haven't attempted something first. This isn't a site where you drop requirements and we code for you.

Comment: This seems like HW, which is even worse.

Comment: @kabanus  It's not a hw, I'm pracitcing for the test and I got stuck, I tried everything that I know..I'm new in programming and I just created acc here. Sorry if I didn't understand how to properly ask a question. I didn't need the whole code, just a little help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I won't give you the full answer, but I'll help you get oriented.

To write recursive functions you need to think of two parts.

1. **Base case** - What is the simplest possible case you could handle? For this problem, that could be when *N* is a 1-digit number.
2. **Recursive case** - Let's say you can handle N-digit numbers. How can you solve N+1-digit numbers, using your 1-digit function and your N-digit function? The answer is, carve off one digit. Feed that digit to the 1-digit checker and the other N digits to the N-digit checker. (The "N-digit checker" is the very function you're writing.)

In pseudo-code, a recursive function is typically structured like so:

```
def recursive_function(n):
    if is_base_case:
        return base_case(n)
    else:
        return combine(
            recursive_function(smaller(n)),
            base_case(bite_sized_chunk(n))
        )
```

Your job is to fill in:

- The `is_base_case` test: is `n` one digit?
- The `base_case` function, which handles only 1-digit numbers.
- The `smaller` function, which gives you all but the last digit of `n`. If `n` is 1234, `smaller(n)` is 123.
- The `bite_sized_chunk` function, which gives you the last digit of `n`. If `n` is 1234, `bite_sized_chunk` is 4.
- The `combine` function, which combines the base case and recursive answers.

(None of these functions need to be actual separate functions. They can be inlined.)